# Exporting PostgreSQL to json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I am trying to export a PostgreSQL database to GEOjson but first I have to export as json.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90482/export-postgres-table-as-json

I have gone over the solutions for the question above but I am getting errors for every single answer.

For:

```
\t
\a
\o file.json
SELECT row_to_json(r) FROM crime AS r;
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "\"
LINE 1: \t
    ^
SQL state: 42601
Character: 1
```

For:

```
\t
\a
\o data.json
select json_agg(t) FROM (SELECT * from crime) t;
```

I set up a data.json txt file and I get the same syntax error.

Comment: How can anyone solve this with the limited information given above? I would suggest you copy and paste a snippet of the text file that you have. question: is the json data you have, valid json?

Comment: What client are you using to do this? Backslash commands are restricted to `psql` client.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon txt file is empty. I'm trying to export the postgres database into json format

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I'm using pgAdmin4 I believe

Comment: Then the above is not going to work. To make it work you need to use the `psql` client.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Is there a way to do it in pgAdmin 4?

Comment: @BrandonNoll i misread the question. if you're trying to output into a json format, it's difficult to solve without a small but complete example of the problem.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon I have 7 columns and around 300k rows in a crime database. Every row has an id, occur date, neighborhood, shift, latitude, longitude, and then theres a geom column for postGIS. I want to export this into json and then geojson format to be used in a map web app. I am trying to figure out how to export this database and format it as json.

Comment: Try [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/121532) from dba.stackexchange.com. But command-line tools more suitable for such tasks.

Comment: If you have Postgres you probably have `psql`. This would be a good time to learn it. `psql` is a lot handier then pgAdmin. If you  want to use pgAdmin then open the QueryTool on the table with the query: `SELECT row_to_json(r) FROM crime AS r;`. Then do a Save As on the results.

Comment: Your query works here. You probably have a BOM in your source file. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark

Answer (score 0):

So, I figured out a more roundabout solution that, though it likely isn't the quickest, can do the same job.

I exported the data from PostgreSQL to .csv and then opened it in Visual Studio Code. Someone made a [very handy extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Chukwuamaka.csvtojson-converter) to Visual Studio Code which can easily convert a .csv file to .json. I hope this information can help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your query works here. You probably have a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in your source file.